# Очистка формы

Tags: javascript, form

Доброго времени суток. Помогите пожалуйста сделать очистку формы.
Нужно чтобы форма полностью очищалась по нажатию на кнопку, после закрытия формы и после обновления страницы.
Вот код:[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/RsvFK/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

поменяйте кнопку на  
    <button type="reset" name="clear" value="Очистить">Очистить</button>

Comment: по закрытию     
`<script>$('a[title="Закрыть"').click(function(){
$("button[type=reset]").click();
})</script>`

Comment: по закрытию формы не работает, и еще нужно чтобы и <label> очищало.

Comment: у элементов формы есть свойство .val в jQuery. Можно очищать так:
$('input[type=text]').val('');

Comment: Если на чистом js, то через метод .setValue() у элемента формы. Лейблы можно очистить задав .innerHTML = '';